# Laravel API middleware - How to retrieve current user without requiring authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I have the following route in my `routes/api.php`

```
Route::get('/games/{game}', 'GamesController@show')->name('api.games.show');
```

On client side, I already included Authorization bearer token header in every AJAX request.

How can I retrieve the value of the user associated with the token throught `$request->user()` without having to require authentication (without having to use `->middleware('auth:api')`)

Basically what I want is to have one route that serves for both authenticated (with token) and non authenticated (without token) requests.

Comment: You would have to create your own middleware to essentially do exactly what `auth:api` already does, which is pseudo-JWT authentication (I believe it actually also uses sessions)

Comment: @Derek that's what I had in mind too but I haven't had the time to dig deeper. I'm hoping someone already solve this issue could give me some snippet.

Comment: Why not just use the pre-built `auth:api` ?

Comment: Facing same issue/ hurdle... did you find a solution?

Comment: In case, if someone will find this question first, here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709659/laravel-5-6-how-to-get-auth-user-or-response-user-in-api-controller
Idk, why this is have higher priority in google