# Unit Testing controller in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-sanctum

I am very new to testing in Laravel, I'm working in laravel 8, the function that I want to test is :

When I run my test I get this error:

> ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50709981/9920875, because I also think you could be passing in the wrong request namespace instead.

Comment: Thank you but I  defined the "use Illuminate\Http\Request;" in my test function and I don't think that should be the problem .

Comment: @Johhn if that were the case, PHP would complain about the parameter not matching the function signature

Comment: What is `$this->user` and where is it defined? Please add this code to your question.

Comment: each order has a user_id and in order to create the order we need to make etablish the connection with a user , I order to generate the user I used a "userFactory" wich generate for me the users while testing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you don't even need to use the `Request` class in your tests.

```php
public function testStore()
{
    Sanctum::actingAs($this->user, ['*']);

    $response = $this->postJson('/order/store', [
        'doAssigned' => false,
        'doValidate' => false,
    ]);

    $response->assertJsonPath('status', 'draft');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help , but I didn't understand what do you mean by "the endpoint" , in my 'api.php' I have :     `Route::apiResource('order', 'OrderController');`

Comment: In my `api.php` I added the line  `Route::get('order/store', 'OrderController@store');` but  I got the error `InvalidArgumentException: Action App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@store not defined.`

Comment: The endpoint is `order/store`. The error you got has to do with namespaces. Instead of `action('App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@store')` you could try just `action('OrderController@store')`, but you could just put the endpoint directly in the test. I just edited it.